# Select files or directories fast by tag or category?

Tags: php

I am trying to build a simple website without database with PHP. I thought about storing each 'post' in a directory.

A directory name would look like `423-name-or-description-for-me` and I would try to select the directory by `423`. (`site.xy/article/423`) After that one could load photos from inside the directory or text files.

But how can I assing one or more 'tags' to such a directory and then list all 'holidays' or 'summer' for example on a page? (`site.xy/category/summer`)

I mean something like this :

```
name: 42-first-holidays
tags: holidays, sweden, summer
```

Perhaps XML files which contain the tags?

```
1-about-us.xml
4-another-article.xml
746-one-more-post.xml
```

I don't know how this could work. Is there a possibility to 'tag' files or directories and then use this to build a simple and fast website?

#### edit:

I saw this at [dokuwiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org/features), (no database just text files)

Comment: Seems like a good use for a database, doing queries like this. I guess you could just make a "tags.txt" file and store something like "123|tag1|tag2" with each id/tag on a line separated by a delimiter (I used `|`). Would be easy to find all lines with a specific tag however, it would be slow and a pain to manage. This is what databases are for. You would almost be better going in reverse and listing `tag|123|124|127`.

Comment: I wouldn't do it outside of a database, databases are extremely fast.  on the order of several thousand selects per second if properly indexed.  Imagine for instance you use summer in multiple sub-folder directory's that will be a Disk intensive search to look thought "who knows how many folders and sub folders" when the database could be done with a simple join and select statement

Comment: That "dokuwiki" looks interesting, it also looks like its python not php, also they probably have several developers, with impressive college degrees, I just say this because, yes It can be done, but in most cases it's much easier, just as fast, and more reliable to use a DB.  In fact there are several NO-SQL databases such as Cassandra that could do things like this without using a traditional DB, not sure if they use something like that.

Comment: they say a filesystem is an efficient place for storing data. thats why I thought it could be faster than a DB https://www.dokuwiki.org/faq:database

Comment: Only if it's a SSD hard drive, and if it's programed in the proper way.  I am not sure how the NO-SQL systems work at that level but it's much more then recursively scanning directory structures.

Comment: Filesystems are efficient for storing data. That does not mean they are fast. It also does not mean it's easy to do what you're looking to do. But just to store it, for a long time, it is good at that. Use a database that is optimized for storing and retrieving data very quickly very often.